# construct positive $L^2$ orthogonal continuous funtion

Tags: continuity, orthogonality

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $C([0,1])$.  For all $v\in V\backslash\{0\}$, there exists $x\in [0,1]$ s.t. $v(x)>0$. Prove that there exists $w\in C([0,1])$ s.t. $ \text{inf}_{[0,1]}w>0$ and $\int_0^1 vw=0, \forall v\in V$.

**My Attempt:**

Since $V$ is a finite dimensional subspacce of $C([0,1])$, we can take a basis, say ${v_1,\cdots,v_n}$. Then we only need to construct a positive continuous funtion $w$ which is  orthogonal  to ${v_1,\cdots,v_n}$ in the sense of $L^2$ inner product. Then I got stuck here. Can anyone give me some hints? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: To prove the existence of such a $w \in C([0,1])$, you may use the Hahn-Banach separation theorem, which states that for any two disjoint non-empty convex sets $A$ and $B$, there exists a continuous linear functional $\varphi$ and a constant $c$ such that $\varphi(a) < c < \varphi(b)$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

Comment: Is it necessary to use tools from Functional Analysis? I think this problem can be solved by   pure  Mathematical Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to approach this problem is to use the Gram-Schmidt process to construct an orthonormal basis for V. Let w1=v1/||v1||
, and for i=2,⋯,n
, let wi
be the orthogonal projection of vi
onto the subspace spanned by w1,⋯,wi−1
, i.e. wi=vi−∑j=1i−1⟨vi,wj⟩⟨wj,wj⟩wj
, where ⟨⋅,⋅⟩
denotes the L2
inner product on C([0,1])
.

Then we claim that the function w=w1+⋯+wn
satisfies the desired properties. First of all, since each wi
is a linear combination of w1,⋯,wi−1
and vi
, it follows that w
is in the subspace spanned by v1,⋯,vn
, and hence w∈V
.

Secondly, since w1,⋯,wn
form an orthonormal basis for V
, it follows that ⟨wi,wj⟩=0
for i≠j
. Therefore, we have ⟨w,w⟩=⟨w1+⋯+wn,w1+⋯+wn⟩=⟨w1,w1⟩+⋯+⟨wn,wn⟩=||v1||2+⋯+||vn||2, which is a positive number by assumption.

Finally, we claim that ∫01vw=0
for all v∈V
. To see why, let v be any function in V
, and let ci=⟨v,wi⟩
. Then we have v=c1w1+⋯+cnwn, and hence

∫01vw=∫01(c1w1+⋯+cnwn)(w1+⋯+wn)dw
=∫01(c1w1⋅w1+⋯+cnwn⋅wn)dw
=c1∫01w21dw+⋯+cn∫01wn2dw
=c1||v1||2+⋯+cn||vn||2
=⟨v,w⟩
=0,

where we have used the fact that w1,⋯,wn
are orthogonal, and hence w1⋅w2=⋯=wn−1⋅wn=0. Therefore, w satisfies all the desired properties.

Answer (score -1):

Since For all $v\in V\backslash\{0\}$, there exists $x\in[0,1]$ s.t. $v(x)>0$

Each basis function is positive somewhere and negative somewhere. Let us separate them out as  $\{v_1^+,v_1^-,...,v_n^+,v_n^-\}$ where $v_i^+ = max\{v_i,0\}$ and $v_i^- = -min\{v_i,0\}$.

Pretty much we just want $w$ where $\int w\ v_i^+ = \int w\ v_i^-$ for all $i$

We start with $w_0 = 0$

Now since $\langle v_1,v_1^+\rangle > 0$, $\langle v_1,v_1^-\rangle < 0$, and $\langle v_1^+,v_1^-\rangle = 0$ we can choose bump functions $f_1^+,f_1^-$ around $x_1^+,x_1^-$ in their support such that $\langle f_1^+ + f_1^-,v_1\rangle = 0$

Write $w_1 = w_0 + f_1^+ + f_1^-$ We have $w_1$ is orthogonal to $v_1$ and positive everywhere. Now we need to make it orthogonal to $v_2,..,v_n$ while remaining positive.

Since $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 0$ we can find $x_{1,2}^+,x_{1,2}^-$ where $v_1 v_2 > 0, v_1 v_2 < 0$ respectively. Then first choose so $\langle w_{2}, v_1 \rangle = 0$ and then scale so $\langle w_{2}, v_2 \rangle = -\langle w_{1}, v_2 \rangle$. Then $\langle w_1 + w_{2}, v_2 \rangle = 0$ as well.

In general we can find points $x_{i,j}^+,x_{i,j}^-$ where $v_i v_j$ is positive, negative. Then scaling bump functions we have in general $\langle w, v_i \rangle = \sum_{j} \langle f_{i,j}^+ + f_{i,j}^-, v_i \rangle$.

We want $\langle w, v_i \rangle = \sum_{j} \hat{r}_{i,j} + \hat{s}_{i,j} = 0$, where $\hat{r}_{i,j} = \hat{r}_{j,i} := \langle f_{i,j}^+, v_i \rangle > 0$ and $\hat{s}_{i,j} = s_{j,i} = \langle f_{i,j}^-, v_i \rangle < 0$

We have $n$ equations with $n(n+1)$ unknowns so solutions should exist if the $v_i$ aren't identical at the selected points.

Comment: 1 can't be a basis element of $V$ because for all $v\in V-\{0\}$, there exists $x \in [0,1] s.t. v(x)>0$, and $1 \in V \implies -1 \in V$, but there does not exist $x$ st $-1 > 0$.

We could have $1$ be a basis of element for $\langle V \cup \{1\} \rangle $ but we don't know that $ \langle v ,1 \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$

Comment: Splitting the basis vectors into $\{v_1^+,v_1^-,...,v_n^+,v_n^-\}$ is just to make a generating set for a space containing $V$ since $v_i = v_i^+ - v_i^-$, and some positive function $w$ orthogonal to $V$

Comment: In **we can choose bump functions $f_1^+,f_1^-$ around $x_1^+,x_1^-$ in their support such that... **,  can you make it more clear about the construction of $f_1^+,f_1^-$?

Comment: In "Then first choose so $\langle w_{2}, v_1 \rangle = 0$ and then scale so ...", what is $w_2$ and what you mean by 'scale' ?